# Error when trying to remote debug in VS2017 with MSVSMON

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I have installed Visual Studio 2017, and when I tried to run a web application it works fine on Internet Explorer, but in Chrome it gives me this error:

> the 32-bit version of the visual studio remote debugger cannot be used to debug 64-bit processes or 64-bit dumps. Please use the 64-bit version instead.

I notice that MSVSMON.EXE is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64` folder, and when I click on it, it runs normally. It is allowed in windows firewall.

If I disable javascript debugging for ASP.NET, it works fine on Chrome but I still want this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I deactivated the firewall and antivirus.