# Visual Studio: Not able to run any project when setting x64 as platform

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

When I run my sample console app on x86, everything works fine. But when I try to use x64, nothing does. I keep on getting this error:

> a 64-bit debugging operation is taking longer than expected

and later it says:

> the connection with the remote endpoint was terminated

I have tried almost every solution online but to no avail.

1. Run cmd.exe as administrator. Type in and run the following commands:
   netsh winsock reset catalog
   tetsh int ip reset reset.log hit
2. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsvc/2013/12/31/visual-studio-debugging-issue/
3. [Error when trying to remote debug in VS2017 with MSVSMON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48114572/error-when-trying-to-remote-debug-in-vs2017-with-msvsmon)
4. [Visual Studio 2012 A remote operation is taking longer than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252969/visual-studio-2012-a-remote-operation-is-taking-longer-than-expected)

I'm using VS 2017. I have observed the same behavior on my VS 2015 as well. Everything was working fine yesterday and suddenly something has happened today because of which x64 has stopped working. I haven't installed any new apps or anything that could cause this.

Really splitting hairs here.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this appears to be an issue with Windows Defender and is being investigated on the Windows side. The workaround shared so far is:

In an elevated PowerShell, run “set-mppreference -EnableNetworkProtection 0”. Relaunch VS.

Comment: This needs a link to the web page so users can track resolution of the problem.

Comment: Here's the link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/212059/unable-to-debug-unit-test-visual-studio-enterprise.html